# React to route change

Tags: svelte, sveltekit

I am trying to build a Web-Application using svelte kit. I got the following route structure:

- [roleId]

  - +layout.ts
  - +page.svelte

The +layout.ts includes a load function that fetches the data from the server.
The +page.svelte consumes the fetched data using `export let data: PageData;`.

I can successfully display and edit a role name with this code:

```
export let data: PageData;
let roleName: string = data.role.name;
...
<TextInput bind:value={roleName} />
```

But when i am changing the url, by clicking on a link (e.g. from "/roles/1" to "roles/2"), it does not update the role name to the new role.

I tried this code to react to an change on the fetched data:

```
export let data: PageData;
$: roleName = data.role.name;
...
<TextInput bind:value={roleName} />
```

And it solves the problem of the not updating the role name on a link click, but it introduces the problem that i cannot change the roleName by updating the value in the TextInput.

As far as i understood the `$:`  syntax, it is used to create a reactive statement, which means that it will be re-evaluated whenever any of its dependencies change.
But why is it triggering a re-evaluation when the roleName changes?

When adding following code to the second example:
`$: console.log(data.role.name);`
It logs the same role name on every keyboard input to the console.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an oddity/potential bug in how dependencies are tracked and not specific to SvelteKit.

The `bind:value` will cause `data` to be invalidated on input, causing a reset, presumably because the reactive statement creates a relationship between `roleName` and `data`, even though it is supposed to be one-way from `data` to `roleName`.

You probably can work around this by not using `bind` and splitting it into input and event:

```html
<TextInput value={roleName} on:input={e => roleName = e.target.value} />
```

(This requires the component to provide the respective event, usually forwarded from some regular `<input>`.)